# How to create animated gif like the mac screensaver with changing photos?

Tags: gif, mac, windows

I want to create animated gif of photos, like the screensaver of macs ?

Which program will do it as default ? I am using windows.

I want to use it in power point.

Comment: Unless the palette of the images are very limitted it wouldnt work out very well.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use an animated GIF?

Comment: I want to put in power point, and any format that is supported will be ok.

Comment: GIF is not suitable for photos, especially lots of them animated. The quality will be terrible and file size huge. Can't you do what you want directly in powerpoint? Or import a video? (I have no idea I havn't used powerpoint in about 15 years).

Answer (score 2):

To answer both your questions and Cai's question, you **CAN** actually do this directly in PowerPoint by adding the photos as slide backgrounds and using slide transitions.

It's literally the best approach not only because a GIF doesn't get along with photos but you can actually go back and edit your images/transitions/styles/time and so on.

So, basically, it's easier, faster, at a better quality and you have more control over it.